# Validation errors (like "Stray start tag html") that I can't seem to shake on header.php

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, w3c-validation

Running validation and getting a few errors.

```
    f<!DOCTYPE html>↩
    <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <![endif]-->↩
    <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> <!--<![endif]-->↩
    <head>↩
```

I've tried saving the header.php as (UTF-8, no BOM), but I can't seem to shake the non-space character (the 'f') at the start.

Here is the PHP Code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
/**
 * Theme Header
 *
 * Outputs <head> and header content (logo, tagline, navigation)
 */
?>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8 no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Then, I have no clue where to start on the "stray html" error tag. Check for yourself http://wsumc.com/worship

Comment: Is there PHP? Where does the `f` come from?

Comment: `DOCTYPE`  must come as first, so remove the `f`

Comment: Show us the actual PHP code.

Comment: @Tom Udding Its a wordpress webside.

Comment: I don't know where the f is coming from - it's not in the php file. ...

Comment: Ok - I found the f ... it was in the parent theme Header file. ... now a whole new set of errors to work through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http://wsumc.com/worship/ …

The *“Stray start tag `html`”* message is just another side effect of that `f` at the beginning.

The way that HTML works is, that `f` is naked text—which a `head` element can’t contain—so it implies that the body of the document has started and that everything that follows is part of the body. So when an HTML parser sees that `f`, the parser generates a  `<body>` start tag.

But the next thing the parser sees is `<!DOCTYPE html>`—which is now in the `body`—so the parser says, *“Stray doctype”* and moves on. But then the next thing the parser finds is an `<html>` start tag, which is now also in the `body`—so the parser says, *“Stray start tag `html`”*.

The [*Parsing HTML documents* section of the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#parsing) defines how all this works (though admittedly not in a super-approachable way for most readers…)